Getting Started with protocol/configuration file builder
I have built an application which delivers a series of "tasks" each written in psychJS (javascript). Each task has a name and a large series of parameters. The platform delivers all of the tasks with the appropriate parameters based on a config file.
I would like to create a browser-based interface where an end-user (non-programmer) can creates this config file. I would there to be an "add task" button which is a pull-down menu where the options are dynamically loaded up from a mySQL call/result. Then the user clicks the added task and a new window opens up where all the parameters are displayed and the end-user makes selections. The parameters will be booleans, pulldowns, or number entry. The required parameters for each task are loaded from a JS file.
The end result is/are config file(s) that the main "task" platform delivers.
I have included examples of the end resultant config files below.
I am asking for direction on how to get started on this. Where to start, what to read, etc. I am comfortable with JS and have a rudementary knowledge of ReactJS. I am thinking this would be a good project for me to learn ReactJS.
Thank you.
var List = []
List.push({Task: 'Screening', Parameters: 'BriefScreening', Instructions: '', IconName: 'Screening'})
List.push({Task: 'Intake Form', Parameters: 'IntakeForm_EN', Instructions: 'Default', IconName: 'Intake'})
List.push({Task: 'Word Recall', Parameters: 'RAVLT_Spoken_Immediate', Instructions: 'Default', IconName: 'Immediate'})
List.push({Task: 'Card Sort', Parameters: 'CardSort_001', Instructions: 'Default', IconName: 'Card Sort'})
List.push({Task: 'Pattern Comparison', Parameters: 'PatternComparison_001', Instructions: 'Default', IconName: 'Patt Comparison'})
List.push({Task: 'Spetial DMS', Parameters: 'SpatialDMS_Adaptive', Instructions: 'Default', IconName: 'Dots'})

BatteryList.push({index: 16, 
    name:'Demo', 
    description: 'Test',
    BatteryInstructions: '<p class="Instructions">Neural Cognitive Mapping Laboratory - <b>Cognitive Evaluation</b>',
    Language:'EN',
    RunAudioTest: true,
    Footer: '©NCMLab 2024',
    TaskList: List,
})


And the parameter file for a single task is:
var RAVLT_Spoken_Delayed = {
    FolderName: 'RAVLT_en_US-Neural2-F_Speed100/',
    WordList: 'RAVLT',
    FileExtension: '.wav',
    NBlocks: 1,
    BListFlag: false, // Check to see if there is a second set of words
    RecallType: 'Spoken',
    RecallDuration: 60, // seconds
    DelayBeforeShowingDoneButton: 10,
    TimePerWord: 1500, // milliseconds
    DelayedRecallFlag: true,
    ShowWelcome: false,
    ShowThankYou: false,
    ShowInstructions: true,
    AskForNotes: false,
}

